# google maps in eclipse birt

Tags: eclipse, birt

Is it possible to use google maps in eclipse BIRT. I am specifically looking for using customized icons in the map and if possible to highlight border of certain towns in US states

If it is possible, can you please guide me to a possible solution

Regards
Arif

Comment: There's the [Visioneo][1] technology as a start. Its community edition is free. 
If you want to do it on your own, you can have a look at this [blog][2].

  [1]: http://www.visioneo.org/google-map
  [2]: http://esitnikov.blogspot.de/2010/01/birt-best-practice_5227.html